# INSERT my_table (fields,...) value (value_1,...), (value_2, ...)... is slow in citus

Tags: postgresql, citus

Environment:

- host:

  - resources:32 cores, 64GB RAM, Docker 24.07
  - OS: CentOS 7
  - disk: 10 separate disk partitions

The 10 separate disk partitions are as below

```
df -h
filesystem            capacity  used  avail used% mount
devtmpfs                  32G     0   32G    0% /dev
tmpfs                     32G     0   32G    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     32G   66M   32G    1% /run
tmpfs                     32G     0   32G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root  168G   16G  153G   10% /
/dev/sde1                9.8T  107M  9.8T    1% /data03
/dev/sdj1                9.8T   33M  9.8T    1% /data08
/dev/sdd1                9.8T  105M  9.8T    1% /data02
/dev/sdl1                9.8T   33M  9.8T    1% /data10
/dev/sdb1                9.8T  1.4G  9.8T    1% /data00
/dev/sdh1                9.8T   33M  9.8T    1% /data06
/dev/sdi1                9.8T   33M  9.8T    1% /data07
/dev/sdf1                9.8T  107M  9.8T    1% /data04
/dev/sdc1                9.8T  107M  9.8T    1% /data01
/dev/sdg1                9.8T   33M  9.8T    1% /data05
/dev/sda1               1014M  226M  789M   23% /boot
tmpfs                    6.3G     0  6.3G    0% /run/user/1010
```

I use below docker-compose.yml to build a 3-node citus cluser in docker, and a standalone postgresql named "pg-16". They all use the same image. The only difference between pg-16 and citus-xxxx container is that I remove `shared_preload_libraries='citus'` from `postgresql.conf` for pg-16. By the way, I didn't change other configuration in postgresql.conf. All default values

```
version: "3.7"


services:

  citus-coordinator:
    image: citusdata/citus:latest
    container_name: citus-coordinator
    hostname: citus-coordinator
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "4"
          memory: "16G"
    ports:
      - 5440:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'

    volumes:
      - /data01/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - /data01/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  citus-worker1:
    image: citusdata/citus:latest
    container_name: citus-worker1
    hostname: citus-worker1
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "4"
          memory: "16G"
    ports:
      - 5441:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'

    volumes:
      - /data02/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - /data02/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  citus-worker2:
    image: citusdata/citus:latest
    container_name: citus-worker2
    hostname: citus-worker2
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "4"
          memory: "16G"
    ports:
      - 5442:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
    volumes:
      - /data03/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - /data03/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data


  citus-worker3:
    image: citusdata/citus:latest
    container_name: citus-worker3
    hostname: citus-worker3
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "4"
          memory: "16G"
    ports:
      - 5443:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
    volumes:
      - /data04/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - /data04/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pg-16:
    image: citusdata/citus:latest
    container_name: pg-16
    hostname: pg-16
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "4"
          memory: "16G"
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
    volumes:
       - /data00/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
       - /data00/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

As you can see in my docker-compose.yml, each citus node (incl. coordinator) uses one disk partition, so that the I/O  of disk partition is not shared by other nodes.

My table `gm_data2` is as below:

```
create table if not exists gm_data2
(
    id bigint not null,
    period_type varchar(2) not null,
    billing_determinates varchar(40),
    file_id bigint not null,
    region varchar(2) not null,
    ratio varchar(8) not null,
    date_created timestamp not null,
    last_updated timestamp not null,
    read_seq varchar(40) not null,
    cyc_dt varchar(3) not null,
    cust_addr varchar(40) not null,
    hes_code varchar(30),
    seg_type varchar(3) not null,
    ctr_type varchar(5) not null,
    custno varchar(20) not null,
    meterno varchar(16) not null constraint gm_data2_pkey primary key,
    tou varchar(5),
    cust_name varchar(30),
    publish_id varchar(5),
    group_id varchar(3),
    reg_ctr_vol varchar(8),
    period_dt varchar(3),
    service_group_id varchar(4),
    read_dt varchar(10),
    billing_mark varchar(2),
    high_low_vol integer
);
```

After the above citus containers are created, I have completed the required actions to configure the cluster

```
dbbench=> SELECT * FROM citus_get_active_worker_nodes();
   node_name   | node_port
---------------+-----------
 citus-worker3 |      5432
 citus-worker2 |      5432
 citus-worker1 |      5432

dbbench=> SELECT create_distributed_table('gm_data2', 'meterno');
 rebalance_table_shards
------------------------

(1 row)

dbbench=> SELECT rebalance_table_shards('gm_data2');
 rebalance_table_shards
------------------------

(1 row)


SELECT count(1)  FROM citus_shards;
 count
-------
    32
(1 row)

dbbench=> SELECT *  FROM citus_shards;
 table_name | shardid |   shard_name    | citus_table_type | colocation_id |     nodename      | nodeport | shard_size
------------+---------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+------------
 gm_data2   |  102040 | gm_data2_102040 | distributed      |             2 | citus-coordinator |     5432 |     565248
 gm_data2   |  102041 | gm_data2_102041 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker1     |     5432 |     581632
 gm_data2   |  102042 | gm_data2_102042 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker2     |     5432 |     557056
 gm_data2   |  102043 | gm_data2_102043 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker3     |     5432 |     892928
 gm_data2   |  102044 | gm_data2_102044 | distributed      |             2 | citus-coordinator |     5432 |     917504
 gm_data2   |  102045 | gm_data2_102045 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker1     |     5432 |     589824
 gm_data2   |  102046 | gm_data2_102046 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker2     |     5432 |     933888
 gm_data2   |  102047 | gm_data2_102047 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker3     |     5432 |     892928
 gm_data2   |  102048 | gm_data2_102048 | distributed      |             2 | citus-coordinator |     5432 |     892928
 gm_data2   |  102049 | gm_data2_102049 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker1     |     5432 |     573440
 gm_data2   |  102050 | gm_data2_102050 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker2     |     5432 |     933888
 gm_data2   |  102051 | gm_data2_102051 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker3     |     5432 |     925696
 gm_data2   |  102052 | gm_data2_102052 | distributed      |             2 | citus-coordinator |     5432 |     892928
 gm_data2   |  102053 | gm_data2_102053 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker1     |     5432 |     573440
 gm_data2   |  102054 | gm_data2_102054 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker2     |     5432 |     917504
 gm_data2   |  102055 | gm_data2_102055 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker3     |     5432 |     909312
 gm_data2   |  102056 | gm_data2_102056 | distributed      |             2 | citus-coordinator |     5432 |     950272
 gm_data2   |  102057 | gm_data2_102057 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker1     |     5432 |     548864
 gm_data2   |  102058 | gm_data2_102058 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker2     |     5432 |     909312
 gm_data2   |  102059 | gm_data2_102059 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker3     |     5432 |     950272
 gm_data2   |  102060 | gm_data2_102060 | distributed      |             2 | citus-coordinator |     5432 |     917504
 gm_data2   |  102061 | gm_data2_102061 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker1     |     5432 |     573440
 gm_data2   |  102062 | gm_data2_102062 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker2     |     5432 |     901120
 gm_data2   |  102063 | gm_data2_102063 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker3     |     5432 |     933888
 gm_data2   |  102064 | gm_data2_102064 | distributed      |             2 | citus-coordinator |     5432 |     917504
 gm_data2   |  102065 | gm_data2_102065 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker1     |     5432 |     581632
 gm_data2   |  102066 | gm_data2_102066 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker2     |     5432 |     917504
 gm_data2   |  102067 | gm_data2_102067 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker3     |     5432 |     876544
 gm_data2   |  102068 | gm_data2_102068 | distributed      |             2 | citus-coordinator |     5432 |     917504
 gm_data2   |  102069 | gm_data2_102069 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker1     |     5432 |     581632
 gm_data2   |  102070 | gm_data2_102070 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker2     |     5432 |     884736
 gm_data2   |  102071 | gm_data2_102071 | distributed      |             2 | citus-worker3     |     5432 |     925696
(32 rows)
```

Now I need to insert 100000 records to a table named `gm_data2`. There are two methods to insert these records.

- method 1 (batch size=1):
  Use below INSERT for each records. That means I need to do 100000 times of INSERT actions

  ```
  INSERT INTO gm_data2 (field11, field12, ...) values (value1_1, value1_2, ...)
  ```
- method 2 (batch size=100000):
  Use batch INSERT to insert the 100000 records into foo_table in one command as below:

  ```
  INSERT INTO gm_data2(field11, field12, ...) values
  (value1_1, value1_2, ...),
  (value2_1, value2_2, ...),
  (value3_1, value3_2, ...),
   .....
  (value100000_1, value100000_2, ...)
  ```

below is my test result. the cell is `seconds`

| server | batch_size=1 | batch_size=1000 | batch_size=10000 | batch_size=100000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| citus cluster | 62.752 | 26.746 | 35.002 | 40.899 |
| pg-16 | 28.908 | 7.876 | 8.375 | 8.909 |

My question is, why a 3-node citus cluster is far slower than that of a standalone pg-16 ? And how to tune this citus performance ?

Comment: You have done excellent work.  Looks like postgresql has something built into it supporting the performance advantage or the hared_preload_libraries in 'citus' are process hogs.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Citus its logic for multi-row inserts is definitely something that would benefit from some more code optimization. Luckily there's a way of bulk loading records that is much faster than multi-row inserts (both with Citus and plain Postgres): Using the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command, or psql its easier to use [`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) wrapper around it.

Some basic example like this would work:

```bash
\copy gm_data2 (field11, field12, ...) FROM '/path/to/some.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV)
```

And to really get the benefit of the multiple citus nodes that you have, you'd want to run multiple of such COPY commands in parallel when loading your data. Since a single COPY command is still only able to use a single CPU core on the coordinator.